# Input data into array until input is char

Tags: c

C newbie here. I wanted to ask how can i fill an array until the user inputs a character. After that the input section stops and it prints them out.

```
    int main()
{
    int a, b[100];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < b[i]; i++){
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return value from `scanf` in a `while` loop as `scanf` returns the number of elements scanned. In your case that would be 1 when the user inputs a number and 0 when the user inputs a char.

So the code could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 100
int main()
{
    int elements = 0; 
    int b[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int i;
    while(elements < 100 && scanf("%d", &b[elements]) == 1)
    {
        ++elements;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
10 20 30 g
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
```